# Who is "we" in Al Kahf?

Tags: quranic-events

Salam. I wanted to seek some clarification on surah Al Kahf. In verse 79, Al Khidr referred to himself as "I",
"As for the ship, it belonged to poor people working at sea. So I intended to cause defect in it as there was after them a king who seized every [good] ship by force." 
but in verse 80, he used "we", 
"And as for the boy, his parents were believers, and we feared that he would overburden them by transgression and disbelief."

Can someone share some islamic sources on who the "we" is (besides Al Khidr of course)?

Answer (score -1):

The answer from the context seems to be that the "we" refers to "Khidr and the parents". There are no sources I could find, but I am basing it on the context.

Comment: Did you tafsir tabari on the verse,  where he mentions different interpretation such as: *"وقوله { فَخَشِينا } وهي فـي مصحف عبد الله «فخَافَ رَبُّكَ أنْ يُرْهِقَهُما طُغْياناً وكُفْراً»"*

Comment: @Kilise . No, I haven't read tafsir Tabari but if you have you should write an answer including that.